# Does sendmail also receive mails?

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail

Like the title says, do sendmail or postfix also take care of incoming emails? Cause I have a site which uses the email service from Amazon for sending emails, but Amazon doesn't also take care of incoming emails, so I don't know how come I'm successfully receiving emails. If sendmail does take care of this, my question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sendmail/postfix will handle incoming mails (but you will likely need some additional service like an IMAP server to actually make them accessible to the users).

What Amazon services offers only sending capabilities?

Comment: Amazon SES (simple email service). It's still beta and it's the only one regarding emails as far as I know. Thanks.